# Primes $p$ such that $432 p +1$ is prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem

Is the set of prime numbers $p$ such that $432 p + 1$ is also prime infinite?

It doesn't follow from Dirichlet's theorem as far as I can tell.

Comment: Replacing $432$ with $2$ gives the Sophie Germain primes, and it isn't known if there are infinitely many of those. Do you expect something nicer from $432$?

Comment: The statement follows from the Hardy–Littlewood conjecture, and as Zack says, is likely wide open.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. Thank you.

Comment: The square-free version of your question has an affirmative answer, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177849/squarefree-numbers-n-such-that-432n1-is-also-squarefree/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a well known open problem -- namely, generalized Hardy-Littlewood conjectures.

Comment: This question needs to be reopened.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, this is open.  Heath-Brown, in "Prime twins and Siegel zeros" showed that if there are infinitely many Landau-Siegel zeros (real zeros near $s=1$ of quadratic Dirichlet $L$-functions), then there are infinitely many twin primes.  His proof is actually more general, and gives under the same hypothesis infinitely many Sophie Germaine primes, or for that matter pairs of primes $(p,q=432p+1)$.

So if it helps, you may assume there are not infinitely many Landau-Siegel zeros...